# How to iterate over "withTags" and "div" in R

Tags: r

```
trial <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
                  
for (i in 1 : 4 ){
  bus <- withTags(
    div(id = i,trial[i]))
  print(bus)
}
```

I would like the output to be :

```
<div id="1">a</div>
<div id="2">b</div>
<div id="3">c</div>
<div id="4">d</div>
```

however I am getting `Error in trial[i] : invalid subscript type 'closure'`.

How do I go forward in this ?

Comment: Is it correct you have a character vector of length 4, and you're trying to access the 5th through 10th elements of that vector?

Comment: ah sorry no , it is i in 1:4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are with `withTags`, that makes functions available for all of the HTML elements. It just so happens that `tags$i` is a function that creates italic elements. This is masking your iterator variable thus inside the function R things that `i` is a function. One solution is to change the name of your iterator

```
for (idx in 1:4 ){
  bus <- withTags(
    div(id = idx, trial[idx]))
  print(bus)
}
```

or skip the withTags and just call

```
for (i in 1:4 ){
  bus <- tags$div(id = i, trial[i])
  print(bus)
}
```

Comment: is there a way I could write the output back to my uploaded txt file? when I am doing it, the file is giving me null output ..

Comment: 'a <- for (idx in 1:4 ){
                                         bus <- withTags(
                                         div(id = idx, trial[idx]))
                                         print(bus)'
                                                                            }

Comment: How exactly are you writing it back to a file currently? Not that a for loop doesn’t ever return a value. It always returns null.

Comment: the uploaded trail txt file should contain : <div id="1">a</div>
<div id="2">b</div> instead a,b ,c , d . How am I supposed to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

#### Using lapply:

```
trial <- letters
buslist <- lapply(
  seq_along(trial),
  function(x, k){
    bus <- withTags(div(id = k,x[k]))
    return(bus)},
  x = trial)
names(buslist) <- letters
# > buslist
# $a
# <div id="1">a</div>
#   
#   $b
# <div id="2">b</div>
#   
#   $c
# <div id="3">c</div>
```

[Output that I don't have enough rep to post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SadtE.png)

Comment: I think `Map(function(x,k) withTags(div(id=k,x)), trial, seq_along(trial))` is an even more direct base-R way to create the same output. But it doesn't seem like that was really the OP's problem.